# Conditionally replace values in column with value from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 5 column dataframe where one column has some NaN's. My goal is to replace these NaN's with the corresponding value in another column.

So if my DF looks like this:

```
YearBuilt     LastModified

1993          2004

1994          NaN

1995          2004
```

I would want to replace the NaN with the corresponding YearBuilt, which is 1994 in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.fillna()` to handle this:

```
df.LastModified.fillna(df.YearBuilt,inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if(df['LastModified'][i].isnull()):
        df.loc[i,'LastModified']==df.loc[i,'YearBuilt']
```